# uploading a file in symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using symfony framework and trying to move the uploaded file to another directory, but the `move_uploaded_file` is not **working** this is my code. I hope someone can help me with this

```
public function addApplicantAction() 
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $em->getConnection()->beginTransaction();

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $contact_number = $_POST['contact_number'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $position = $_POST['position'];
    $job_id = $_POST['job_id'];
    $status = "NO";

    $timezone = "Asia/Manila";

    if(function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')) date_default_timezone_set($timezone);

    $date_default = date('m/d/y',mktime(0,0,0,4,5,2010));
    date("m/d/y");
    $time = time();
    $dats = mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d"),date("Y"));
    $date_applied=date("F j, Y ", $dats);

    $upload_dir = $this->getRequest()->server->get('DOCUMENT_ROOT') . '/admin1/web/front/files';
    $valid_extensions = array('doc', 'docx', 'pdf'); // valid extensions
    $path = $upload_dir; // upload directory

    if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
        $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        // get uploaded file's extension
        $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

        // check's valid format
        if (in_array($ext, $valid_extensions)) {
            $path = $path.strtolower($file);

            if (move_uploaded_file($tmp,$path)) {
                $add = new Applicants();

                $add->setFirstName($first_name);
                $add->setLastName($last_name);
                $add->setContactNumber($contact_number);
                $add->setEmail($email);
                $add->setResume($file);
                $add->setPosition($position);
                $add->setStatus($status);
                $add->setDateApplied($date_applied);
                $add->setJobId($job_id);

                $em->persist($add);
                $em->flush();
                $em->commit();
            }
        }
    }

    return new Response('success');  
}
```

Comment: Check if permissions a correct for the directory where you're uploading.

Answer (score 1):

You have written a set of PHP code to process your request data.

If you are using `Symfony Framework`, you shouldn't consume post data directly from `$_POST`. Instead try to use [Symfony Form Type](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/forms/types.html) and take its benefit such as

- entity based validation.
- Data Request handler (creation of object with request data)
- CSRF token security.

Coming back to file upload issue,

- Check the path you are using to move the file and make sure you have correct path set.
- Make sure you have `enctype= multipart/form-data` attribute in your HTML `form` tag.

If you change your mind to use `Symfony FormType`, Check [this docuemnt](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/controller/upload_file.html) for how to upload files in Symfony.